# Ember: same route, different paths

Tags: ember.js, routes, url-routing

I would like a route to be called in 3 different ways:

```
  this.route('issue', {path: '/foo/:param1'});
  this.route('issue', {path: '/foo/:param1/:param2'});
  this.route('issue', {path: '/foo/:param1/:param2/:param3'});
```

But when I try to link-to for example using:

```
{{#link-to 'issue' issue.id issue.tag}}{{/link-to}}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: You didn't provide enough string/numeric parameters
to satisfy all of the dynamic segments for route issue
```

I tried to change the order of the calls in the router, without success. I think I'm lacking some comprehension on how the routes are detected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would probably make sense to use query params here instead. So in the router just define one route:

```
this.route('issue', {path: '/foo/param1'});
```

And then in controller define query params for param2 and param3:

```
export default Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ['param2', 'param3'],
  param2: null,
  param3: null
});
```

You can then use these to [filter your data](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/routing/query-params/#toc_specifying-query-parameters).I am assuming that param1 defines the actual model but 2 and 3 are use for filtering but you can make all of them optional by moving all three to queryParams.

You can set as many (or none) of the query params in the link-to helper:

```
{{#link-to "posts" (query-params direction="asc")}}Sort{{/link-to}}
```

Here is some documentation on query params, which is one of the cooler Ember features in my opinion: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/routing/query-params

Comment: Yeah this works too. I would be happy to have some more infos on how the mapping works in ember. Thanks anyway =)